# Why are there so many Probability law and when do we use them?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm not using maths professionally but I'm curious about Data Sciences and Probability in general.

There are so many Probability laws but I don't understand the motivation.

I guess they will be used in Statistics but are they chosen by hand or are there more rigorous process ?

Why do we need them ?

Comment: When you say "Probability laws", do you mean theorems or distributions?

Comment: In either case, there are many because probability is a productive, interesting and useful area of mathematics. Similarly in Geometry there are many theorems and shapes for similar reasons

Comment: I meant "Normal Law", "Poisson Law", "Pareto Law". I think I'm talking about distribution.

Comment: There are also many different sizes of shoes.  Why do we need them?  Why can't there be just one shoe size?

Comment: The most obvious things are the least obvious things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By probability laws, I think you meant about probability distributions. Apart from the theoretical perspective, the reason we study these distributions in great detail is because we can model many of our real-world scenarios with the help of these distributions. For example, the normal distribution can model the different heights in a population, a poison distribution can model the number of emails you'll receive in the next hour, etc. Hope this answers your question

Comment: Ok, so there is a difference between the theoretical study and the modelization which could be subjective ? I can decide that this probability distribution fits this situation ?

Comment: No, it's not subjective per se, but it may be possible that one distribution may fail to model some scenario. For example, you take a class of students and see that their test scores follow a normal distribution. But suppose, if you leak the question paper to some students before a test, they might end up skewing the distribution towards the right that it may become a bimodal distribution and can no longer be modeled using a normal distribution. The choice of choosing a distribution to model some common data is fairly general however exceptions may arise sometimes.